# Fading red to white to blue continuous loop on ws2812 LED strip

Tags: rgb-led

I'm a big noob when it comes to writing a sketch and have set myself a task for an upcoming 4th July project, which has come to a halt.

I'm trying to set a strip of 30 LEDs to fade from red to white to blue through FastLED on a Wemos D1 mini. I also wanted it to flash each colour after the 3 colours have faded and continuously loop these.

I have searched many different forums and managed to get the fade to go from red to blue, but can't for love nor money add the white in-between.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

```cpp
#include "FastLED.h"
#define NUM_LEDS 30
#define DATA_PIN D4
#define COLOUR_ORDER GRB

CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

void setup() { 

    FastLED.addLeds<WS2811, DATA_PIN, GRB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);

}
void loop(){

    //start from red
    for( int colorStep=0; colorStep <= 255; colorStep++ ) {

        int r = 255;
        int g = 0;
        int b = colorStep;

        // Now loop though each of the LEDs and set each one to the current color
        for(int x = 0; x < LED_COUNT; x++){
            leds[x] = CRGB(r,g,b);
        }

        // Display the colors we just set on the actual LEDs
        delay(10); 
        FastLED.show();
    }

    //into blue
    for( int colorStep=255; colorStep >= 0; colorStep-- ) {

        int r = colorStep;
        int g = 0;
        int b = 255;

        // Now loop though each of the LEDs and set each one to the current color
        for(int x = 0; x < LED_COUNT; x++){
            leds[x] = CRGB(r,g,b);
        }

        // Display the colors we just set on the actual LEDs
        delay(10); 
        FastLED.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you correct your spelling and add some punctuation, to make it easier to read, you may get an answer.

Comment: Also, post what code you have.

Comment: Have you managed to make it turn white on its own, no fading.

Comment: Here is a sketch i got and im unsure how to add the white although i can get it to white on its own using a sketch i found using rgb code.

Comment: not sure how to import sketch to this as im new but i edited my question sorry abut the font change

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: Also check [a FastLED example](https://github.com/FastLED/FastLED/blob/master/examples/ColorPalette/ColorPalette.ino).

Comment: Thank you for your help i should be able to sort it now gre_gor much apreciated

Answer (score -1):

Think of a color as a point in 3d as defined by its r g b attributes

Think of two points here, one is your starting color in that 3d space, and another your ending color.

Figure out the path you want to take from the starting color to the ending cokor.

Chop it up in a few steps and use your code to walk the path.

Done